# "Mixed model ANOVA with random effect"--is this the correct analysis?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

Question about an analysis that was done for a study I'm reviewing:

The study compared two methods of taking patient core temperature around surgery at a single center; Apx. N=200, temp was taken for all patients at 4 timepoints (pre, intraop, post1, post2) simultaneously with both systems.

The write-up says they used a "**Mixed model ANOVA** with patient included as a random effect."

I'm not a statistician but this doesn't sound right? Why would you use patient as a random effect? Also, from the looks of their table [mean(sd) at each time point for both systems, then the mean(sd) of the difference, then a p-value], it looks like they really just used multiple Wilcoxon or t-tests).

i.e. what would be a correct test in this case? and should it involve random effects? Thank you.

Comment: As I understand, you might use a random effect to account for different levels of an explanatory variable (e.g. if there were multiple centers where patients were recruited from); but I don't see how the concept applies to a reasonably representative sample of subjects from a single source population.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the same patient provides repeated response measurements over time (e.g., core temperature), the use of a random patient effect is a natural way to capture the within-patient correlation (or similarity) of those measurements over time.

Mixed Model Anova is an analysis which can be applied to analyze repeated measures data for a set of subjects. It's not clear what fixed effects were investigated in this analysis from the description you provide - the fixed effects of Method and Time and their interaction? You can ask clarifications about that.  Also, it seems the analysis in question assumed that the correlation between core temperatures for the same patient on the same treatment did not depend on how close/far in time those measurements were.  I have a feeling there may be correlation between measurements coming from the same patient at the same time point - not clear whether the analysis used could adequately deal with this, so perhaps that could be listed as a limitation.

Since the difference in mean values of core temperature between Methods was tested at each of the four time points, you should also ask for clarification on whether the reported p-values for these tests were adjusted for testing multiplicity.

Comment: So bear with me @Isabella, but a couple things that may or may not need clarification- 1) there isn't really a "treatment group" designation per se, since all patients were selected from the same surgical population, and were each assessed with both methods; and 2) I don't know if 'time' would be a fixed effect, since each measurement is taken at a discrete (pre/peri/post) timepoint that they've considered particularly "high risk"?

Comment: It's really like a validation study, though neither method is really established enough to be considered a 'gold standard'. I think that's why they ultimately used multiple rank tests, since they were curious about each time point _individually_ ...although a) there's not really a reason methods should be similar at one time point and not at others, and b)  p-values were not adjusted for testing multiplicity.

Again, please excuse my lack of statistical background - but given the above, should I stick with the Mixed Model Anova w/ random effect? Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Sgolenbo: In this study, treatment = mehod.  So there are two method groups. Each group will have a certain "average" temporal profile over time when it comes to core temperature. It looks like the interest is in comparing this "average" profile between groups at each time point.

Comment: If you just have to review the methodology of study, why do you have to analyze the data?

Comment: I don't understand enough about what was done in this study to comment pertinently on what you should do in response to what was done.

Comment: The original analysis was done by an analyst who's since left, and didn't really document what he did. I was asked to review it, since the PI, who's a practitioner, doesn't really know how to discuss the statistics. But now I'm realizing it's incomplete and should probably just be redone (my background is epi and not biostats, so I know just enough to know that I needed help...)


Anyways, I've been reading up on using random effects and it's starting to coalesce now. Above was very helpful for context - thanks again for sticking with me.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - I thought you just needed to comment on it, not re-do it. I agree with you that it is best to re-do it - this is the best way to ensure you know what was done at every step. If you re-do it, why not fit a linear mixed effects model to the data - this will give you more flexibility. In your model, you can code Method and Time as categorical variables and then include them as fixed effects in your model, along with an interaction between them. Allow the model to include a random subject effect and - if necessary, a random effect of Time.

Comment: Robert Long's response was equally helpful - too bad you are not allowed to pick two responses as your preferred response!

Comment: Yep both of you were very helpful - I met with the PI and am in fact redoing it, so will try fitting the linear mixed effects model coded as you described. Thanks so much for all of your help @Isabella!

Answer (score 6):

You *would* use patient as a random effect because there are repeated measures within each patient. This means that observations within one patient may be more similar to each other than observations between patients. In other words there will be correlation within each cluster (patient). In order to handle this non-independence of observations, it is common to include the clustering variable (patient in this case) as a random effect.

Including patient as a random effect is a perfectly reasonable thing to do here, and if it was *not* done, that would likely be a mistake unless another method to control for clustering was used (such as generalised estimating equations, which is obviously not the case here).

Comment: OK, I see. Yes it looks like they did not in fact do that, judging from the SAS code I found, but glad to know that's the appropriate approach to take. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the SAS procedure I would use? PROC GLM w/ random statement? Or PROC MIXED? I'm going by this (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect054.htm), but obviously don't have a great background for the theory.

Comment: @Sgolenbo sorry, but I have never used SAS